# Is there a free online resource where I can get the solubility of a solute in a solvent?

Tags: solubility, solutions

I'm looking for a online resource that lets me find the solubility at of any solute (e.g Choline Chloride, Sodium Hydroxide, Dextrose) in any solvent (e.g. Ethylene Glycol, Oleic Acid, Isopropanol, Water). Preferably, I'd like a webpage that lets me enter solute and solvent, then gives the answer, but even just lookup tables would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to narrow down your question.  Currently, the potential solutes include NaOH (inorganic salt), dextrose (organic neutral compound), and choline chloride (organic quaternary ammonium salt) on one hand, and on the other hand a wide range of potential solvents.  It is unlikely a single database will (ever) cover such a  broad range of possibilities.

Nevertheless, there are some resources that may be useful to consult.  For example solubility tables [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table) or the properties tables for some of the compounds in wikipedia, like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choline).  If you know both solvent, and solute, NIST-IUPAC's solubility database [here](https://srdata.nist.gov/solubility/sol_detail.aspx?sysID=62_223) may be worth to visit.

If your institution / library provides access to Reaxys/Beilstein (a commercial database by Elsevier), you may find solubility data in the category of *physical properties*. This database covers both organic and inorganic (including metal organic) compounds and will provide you both the numerical value, as well the primary reference.

Comment: Reaxys/Beilstein sounds really interesting, but I don't have an institution / library that provides access. is there any kind of public portal to it?

Comment: @Cassie http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57110/solubility-data

Comment: @Buttonwood: This is a great link / idea but it seems to be dead (when I click on it at least).

Comment: @Hand The first three links point to Wikipedia, all functional.  The fourth (nist.gov) requires e.g., NoScript for the Firefox web browser to enable JavaScript.  The link to the chatroom still is accessible when NoScript is temporarily switched-off, too, with pointers to materials.springer.com, CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics, Perry's Chemical Engineers' Handbook, etc.